# Sum specific rows in Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, datatables

In dataframe:

```
cart 5000, 
checkout 3000, 
purchase 2000, 
confirmation 1500.
```

How I can I do:

```
Cart =cart+checkout+purchase+confirmation=11500, 
Checkout =checkout+purchase+confirmation=6500, Purchase=purchase+confirmation=4500, 
confirmation=confirm=1500
```

I want to see them in a table like:

```
       Cart     Checkout      Purchase      Confirmation
User   11500    6500          4500          1500
```

Comment: are you using python?

Comment: Hello :), I use R

Answer (score 0):

if you use python and pandas,consider your dataframe as `df`

```
for i,val in enumerate(df.columns):
    df[val] = df.iloc[:,i:].sum(axis=1)
```